# gdb only shows xmm registers

Tags: gdb, avx2, tui

I have written a subroutine using the avx2 instruction set (ymm registers), and now I want to debug it. My machine supports this instruction set, and the program can be executed without problems (no SIGILL exception).

But when I type 'tui reg vector' or 'info all-registers' to the gdb, it only shows the xmm registers. And the print command is not working, too:

`(gdb) p $ymm0
$1 = void
(gdb) p/x $ymm0
$2 = Value can't be converted to integer.`

I use the most current version gdb-8, so I think, it should know the avx2 instruction set.
How can I persuade the debugger showing the hole ymm registers?
Are there some config files I can edit to tell gdb the instruction set it shold use?

Kind regards

Comment: `tui reg vec` is nearly unusable for YMM registers; they're too wide and it always shows all formats.  I use `p /x $ymm0.v8_int32` or whatever.

Comment: Or `display /x $ymm0.v8_int32`, `display /x $ymm1.v8_int32` to get some registers printed after every `si`.

Comment: Of course, tui has some disadvantages. But that's offtopic. I just edited my question, so you can see it.

Comment: Ah, that's a problem.  I haven't update my Arch Linux system recently enough to get gdb 8, so I haven't seen that.